# Proper way to start Task in .net 4.0

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a class with methods like `Task<byte[]> DoSmthAsync()`
When i try to start this Task from ViewModel ICommand void method it launches synchronously

```
void DoSomeCommand()
{
  //log managed thread id ...
  _someClass.DoSmthAsync().ContinueWith(resultTask => ...);
}
```

if i log CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId outside and inside task it appears to be the same

```
Thread #9 - outside
Thread #9 - inside task
Thread #4 - inside inside task // does not matter
Thread #9 - continuation
```

to launch this task as async i was forced to create new Task with `() =>  _someClass.DoSmthAsync().ContinueWith(resultTask => ...)` action and call `Start()` for it, but i think this is wrong way to do it.

I use .NET 4.0 and can't use async-await, where i never had such problem btw.

Inner task is created with `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
public Task<byte[]> ProcessDataFromPortAsync(byte[] outData)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
  // some event handling  ... 
  WritePortData(outData);
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `async` on .NET 4.0 if you install the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package.

Answer (score 1):

No that is the right way. You are returning a Task from the `DoSmthAsync()` method and if you follow the TPL guidlines, this must be started inside the asynchronious method

```
private Task<byte[]> DoSmthAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew<byte[]>(() => 
        {
            // Some stuff.
        });
}
```

Then this can be consumed in another method

```
private void Method()
{
    Task<byte[]> task = DoSmthAsync().ContinueWith(ant => 
        {
            // Some other stuff.
        });
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is great when you start task by Task.Factory.Start. But what should i do when task created by 'TaskCompletionSource' (added to question)

Comment: Why use that at all? The `TaskCompletionSource`represents the producer side of a Task<TResult> unbound to a delegate... Here you are doing nothing with it what-so-ever. You need to assign the completion source to a `Task` and start that task.